# Uso de Swingworker em conexão com banco standalone

Tags: java, swing, hsqldb, swingworker

Tenho um aplicativo em java que fiz no meu trabalho, para controlar sequência de numeração de ofícios, o mesmo fica em formato jar na rede(fiz usando swing  em java + HSQLDB).

Um problema que não chega a ser crítico, mas incomodava um pouco é o fato do banco citado atrasar a abertura do app(provavelmente por estar em uma pasta da rede e este banco carrega todo o arquivo DB na memória antes de abrir), após analisar pelo determinador de perfil do Netbeans, pude chegar a esta conclusão também.

Pesquisei sobre swingworker e então adaptei minha classe fábrica de conexao() para realizar a abertura e fechamento de conexão e recursos em Thread paralela, e isto fez o programa ter uma resposta melhor.

Minha dúvida é a forma como está implementada o paralelismo nesta classe pode gerar algum problema que eu não esteja enxergando neste momento?

Classe factory com swingworker

```
package com.dfmachado.geroficios.Models;

import com.dfmachado.geroficios.excecoes.ExcecaoErroIO;
import com.dfmachado.geroficios.excecoes.ExcecaoPadrao;
import com.dfmachado.geroficios.utils.Propriedade;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

/**
 *
 * @author diego
 */
public class ConnectionFactory {

    private static String url = null;
    private static Propriedade prop = null;
    private static boolean openConnWorkerIsDone = false;
    private static boolean closeConnWorkerIsDone = true;

    private ConnectionFactory() {
    }

    public static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            prop = new Propriedade();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ExcecaoErroIO(ex.getMessage());
        }
        url = prop.getJdbcURL() + prop.getDbName();

        try {
            if(closeConnWorkerIsDone)
            return OpenConnWorker(url, prop.getUser(), prop.getUserPass());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            throw new ExcecaoPadrao(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        close(conn, null, null);
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        close(conn, ps, null);
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn, PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        close(conn, ps, rs);
    }

    private static void close(final Connection conn, final PreparedStatement ps, final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        if (openConnWorkerIsDone) {
            SwingWorker closeConnWorker = new SwingWorker() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    closeConnWorkerIsDone = false;
                    if (rs != null) {
                        rs.close();
                    }
                    if (ps != null) {
                        ps.close();
                    }
                    if (conn != null) {
                        if (prop.getDbTipo().equals("HSQL")) {
                            conn.prepareStatement("shutdown compact").execute();
                        }
                        conn.close();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    super.done();
                    closeConnWorkerIsDone = true;
                }
            };
            closeConnWorker.execute();
        }
    }

    private static Connection OpenConnWorker(final String url, final String user, final String pass) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Connection conn;
        SwingWorker OpenConnWorker = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                openConnWorkerIsDone = false;
                return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                super.done();
                openConnWorkerIsDone = true;
            }
        };
        OpenConnWorker.execute();
        conn = (Connection) OpenConnWorker.get();
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após analisar alguns tópicos e ler um pouco a documentação e fazer testes, cheguei a conclusão que o uso do *SwingWorker* não é recomendado para este caso, uma vez que o aplicativo é *StandAlone*, e o uso de threads só seria refletido no computador de quem o executa no momento, além de esbarrar em uma restrição do HSQLDB, onde conexões StandAlone só só funcionam uma por vez, então, se várias pessoas acessarem ao mesmo tempo, o método singleton só vai funcionar pra máquina de uma por vez.